# Postgresql natural sort with numbers first

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, natural-sort

In Postgres I need to sort text with natural order, but with one exception - if the string has only number, it should be placed at top.
So I need such order:

```
["98", "125", "134", "148", "265", "634", "1233", "5231",  "1m1ds", "1m2", "1m3", "1n3", "1w3r", "2m3", "2n3ds", "9t6","12gh", "13jy","25hg", "123y", "des2", "nme", "wer5"]
```

I tried with this:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION IF NOT EXISTS numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');
ALTER TABLE "baggage_belts" ALTER COLUMN "name" type TEXT COLLATE numeric;
```

and it is ok, but numbers are mixed into numbers+text:

```
[1m1ds, 1m2, 1m3, 1n3, 1w3r, 2m3, 2n3ds, 9t6, 12gh, 13jy, 25hg, 98, 123y, 125, 134, 148, 265, 634, 1233, 5231, des2, nme, wer5]
```

Anyone has knowledge is it possible make it works with "empty" numbers first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should add a second `ORDER BY` expression that checks for non-digits:

```
ORDER BY name ~ '[^[:digit:]]', name
```

This relies on `FALSE < TRUE`, and you can support it with a two-column index defined like the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution - it works. 
Now I have next obstacle. I need to force this Order By to be used by this spring JPA function:
Iterable<BaggageBeltEntity> findAll(Specification<BaggageBeltEntity> buildSpecification, Sort sort);
Maybe anybody knows how to do it? It is impossible to provide such expression: name ~ '[^[:digit:]]' as Sort property.

Comment: No idea. Can't you write an SQL query?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the approach, but in that case I need to resign from Specification, which I rather wouldn't

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that ORM.

Comment: I need to go back to the question. Is to possible to modify this order to sort digits with that way: 001, 01, 02... 1, 2? Now, there is: 01, 1, 02, 2 etc.

Comment: If you want that, why did you use `colNumeric=yes`?

Comment: Because without this colNumeric=yes numbers are mixeed into alphanumeric entries. I need to such order:
001, 002, 01, 02, 1, 2, 13, 15, 1a, 1ab, 2a, 2ab etc.
Maybe I could use another collation?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the problem by creating additional property into Entity with @Formula:

```
@Formula(value = "name ~ '[^[:digit:]]'")
public String nonDigitName;
```

and now I have

```
Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "nonDigitName", "name")
```

I have one more challenge. I would like to move this property to another class MySortClass and make my base entity class extends MySortClass. But when I moved the property, I have

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nonDigitName] on this ManagedType [pl.ppl.szopl.app.baggagebelt.BaggageBeltEntity]
```

Is there any possibility to Sort by inherited fields?